# Why does the -abigen option in eosio.cdt not work?

Tags: abi, eosio.cdt, compilation, eosio-cpp, abigen

When trying to compile my contract, I use the `-abigen` flag in order to auto-generate the necessary ABI file. This did not work, and gave no errors or warnings.

The code to compile the contract is as follows:

```
eosio-cpp ../src/mycontract.cpp -o mycontract.wasm -abigen
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution to my problem was that the `wasm` file had to exactly match the name of the contract in the attributes of the contract class. So as my file was called `mycontract.wasm`, I had to have the following in my contract class:

```
class [[eosio::contract("mycontract")]] token : public contract { // the name of the class must be mycontract
...
};
```

After this, the ABI Generator worked as expected.